# Undeclared identifier when compiling PerlRegExp in Delphi

Tags: regex, delphi, delphi-2009, pcre

I want to use TPerlRegExp (from http://www.regular-expressions.info/delphi.html, halfway down the page) in my project in Delphi 2009.

I added PerlRegEx.pas and pcre.pas to my project group, and put 'PerlRegEx' in my uses list.

When I compile, I get the following errors:

> [DCC Error] PerlRegEx.pas(305): E2003 Undeclared identifier:
>   'pcre_dispose'
>
> [DCC Error] PerlRegEx.pas(533): E2003 Undeclared identifier:
>   'pcre_dispose'
>
> [DCC Fatal Error] test.dpr(21): F2063 Could not compile used unit
>   '..\Shared\Classes\TPerlRegEx\PerlRegEx.pas'

When I comment out the lines using 'pcre_dispose', it compiles ok. But I don't want to create memory leaks by not freeing things of course...so what might be causing this?

Anyone who has an idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which [`one of them`](http://i.imgur.com/f4tEw.png) have you downloaded ? Could you include the exact link to the version you've used ?

Comment: I tried with both, and both give the same problem.
Currently I am including the files from the latest version: http://www.regular-expressions.info/download/TPerlRegEx.zip.

Comment: Jedi Code Library also have wrapper around PCRE. Tried it ?

Comment: @Arioch'The Didn't try it yet, because I have a much older installation of Jedi in use for other projects that I can't just update without consequences. And I suppose I can't use different versions side by side.
Or can I install just the PCRE wrapper component?

Comment: you may try to extract it and embed into your version, i don't know how many dependencies on other parts of JCL it would have so how much work to be done to plumber it

Comment: PerlRegEx is a much better wrapper than the one included in JCL, IMO. I just used the link you provided in your comment above to download the file to my system, unzipped it into a new folder, started a new XE2 console project, added the path to the new folder from above. I declared a `Regex: TPerlRegex;` variable, wrote a simple `Regex.Subject` and `Regex.Regex` setup and an `if Regex.Match then WriteLn(Regex.MatchText);`. It compiled and ran just fine. Do you have more than one copy of PerlRegex on your machine? (Perhaps one from an earlier pre-Unicode version?)

Comment: @KenWhite where exactly did you add the path to that TPerlRegEx-folder?
I just added the two .pas files to my project, but maybe that's not the way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Project->Options->Compiler->Search Path.

Comment: It was already added in Delphi's Options, and therefore appeard in the project's search path inherited. If I make a new empty project, it seems to work just fine... :/

Comment: Use SysInternals Process Monitor to check which pcre files, pas and dcu and inc, are used by old and new projects. Maybe there is a difference.

Comment: @Arioch'The Why do you suggest JCL?! OP wants to use the excellent `TPerlRegEx`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan since his original report was that TPRE does not work in 2009. Then alternative wrapper might do the trick. If he initially told that TPRE works with new project, then the suggestion could be different.

Comment: " I just added the two .pas files to my project, but maybe that's not the way to do it?" of course it is not. The code is in dozens of .obj files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step by step for a working install (from the download link you provided in the comments to the original question):

Extract the Zip file into a folder. I used `E:\Code\PerlRegEx\XE2`, because I have a non-Unicode version installed for D2007 already.

Start a new console project with `File->New->Other->Console App`.

Use `Project->Options->Compiler` from the IDE's main menu, and add the path location from above into the `Search Path`. Paste the following code to replace everything in the Code Editor:

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, PerlRegex;

var
  Regex: TPerlRegex;

begin
  try
    Regex := TPerlRegex.Create;
    try
      Regex.Subject := 'This is a test of TPerlRegex';
      Regex.RegEx := '\btest\b';
      if Regex.Match then
        WriteLn('Found match: ' + Regex.MatchedText)
      else
        WriteLn('Can''t be! No match found!');
      ReadLn;
    finally
      Regex.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

As you can see, I've used a very complex test of the functionality of `TPerlRegex` for this test case. :-)

If the above works for you, and you're still having problems in your own project:

1. Check your old project for a reference to an old version of TPerlRegex (another folder in the search or library path, an entry in Tools->Options->Environment->Library Path).
2. Check the uses clause (you can use Search->Find in Files, check All Files in Project) for PerlRegex.
3. Make sure you followed the exact steps above: Add PerlRegex's folders to your Project->Compiler->Search Path settings, add PerlRegex to the uses clause of the unit you want to use it in. If it works in the code from my example on your machine, but doesn't in your other project, the problem is there

Comment: U use XE2. That maybe 2009-local problem, like bugs in compiler or wrong $IfDefs

Comment: @KenWhite It comes complaining that it can't find the PerlRegex.dcu :/ There is a DCU in the TPerlRegExp folder though...
I realize I'm a newbie, sorry...

Comment: Ok, now it does compile, your example...all I did was check the IDE's Options...I did not change them. But my original project still doesn't. So weird!!

Comment: @SonOfGrey " I just added the two .pas files to my project, but maybe that's not the way to do it?" - remove them

Comment: @Arioch'The Thanks, did that but the problem remains. Already deleted the DCU's and rebuilt them through the test example from Ken, but I still get the 'Undeclared indentfier pcre_dispose'-errors...

Comment: Which PCRE files does old project and new project read during compilation attempt? Those are pas, dcu and obj files. Compare the lists.

Comment: @Arioch'The Sorry but where can I find those lists?

Comment: in comments above: Use SysInternals Process Monitor to check which pcre files, pas and dcu and inc, are used by old and new projects. Maybe there is a difference. – Arioch 'The 28 mins ago

Comment: This is the log from the project that works: http://imgur.com/4JiDr. This is the one from the project that doesn't work: http://imgur.com/4UcFF. I can't see where the problem is...besides the fact that the one with the problem does not access the pcre.pas file...

Comment: 1. Check your old project for a reference to an old version of TPerlRegex (another folder in the search or library path, an entry in `Tools->Options->Environment->Library Path`). 2. Check the uses clause (you can use `Search->Find in Files`, check `All Files in Project`) for `PerlRegex`. 3. Make sure you followed the exact steps above: Add PerlRegex's folders to your `Project->Compiler->Search Path` settings, add `PerlRegex` to the uses clause of the unit you want to use it in. If it works in the code from my example on your machine, but doesn't in your other project, the problem is there.

Comment: Oh damn...I did a file search on 'pcre' on my whole C disk and found another version that came with an older Jedi package :( Oh I hate these kinds of reasons! Anyway...is there a way to remove just a single part from a Jedi pack?

Comment: Nevermind...I'll find out in what package it resides, and uncheck it in the 'Install Packages' window. Thanks a LOT you guys for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you got it sorted out. I moved my additional suggestions up into the answer itself, since they ultimately helped you figure things out, so that anyone finding this in the future can see them without having to read the comments.

Comment: I suppose it's not possible to leave the Jedi packages intact and still use the PerlRegex? So maybe there's a way to ignore a certain component or so on a project basis? I'm afraid that if I start messing around with the Jedi files, I'll break other stuff...

Comment: JclPCRE isn't in a design-time package, so the problem is that the compiler/linker is finding the JCL version of the PCRE files before it finds the PerlRegEx ones. Try changing the order of the PerlRegEx path (in Project->Options->Search Path) to move it ahead of the JEDI ones, or put it in the global lists in `Tools->Options->Environment Options->Delphi Options->Library Paths` and try it before the Jcl paths. If you're not using the Jcl PCRE stuff, it won't matter that it finds the different ones first, since the Jcl version won't be compiled.

Comment: I really hate it but I think I'm going to have to give up on this one. I removed all files with 'pcre' in their names under JEDI folders to some backup folder on my desktop, put the paths of TPerlRegEx everywhere I could before the JCL paths...and still I get the same error. I suppose I'm just going to have to put the JCL files back and try to use the older JCL version...

Comment: @SonOfGrey please, don't show the raw data in reduced screenshot format.
Why don't you filter the junk out ? Set filter on path to either contain "pcre." or contain "RegEx." - the dot should filter out random file searches in those folders.
Then you can save the search results to plain text file like CSV and either upload those texts to pastebin it or compare yourself with any tool like WinMerge.sf.net Graphical screenshots are hard to analyze and have very little info.

Comment: > still I get the same error - try project clean and project build. It looks like some stray DCU still is lying around. Make new log and check for differences, either attentively or by WinMerge-liek comparer.

Comment: `pcre_dispose` is defined in `pcre.pas` at approximately line 451 in the version you linked to above. It's used in `TPerlRegEx.pas` in `TPerlRegEx.CleanUp` at line 305. If the function can't be found, you've got something off with the JCL stuff, because it's there in `pcre` unless a certain compiler configuration is used (see the `pcre.pas` unit, line 450). I can't see anywhere that define is touched anywhere in the code, and I just tested the install of TPerlRegEx again on a different system (this time XE3) and it works fine "out of the box" where it's never been installed before. It's JCL.